# Install older headers

Tags: system-installation

I am attempting to install an amd-catalyst video card driver after purchasing a new card.  The installer requires linux-kernel-headers 3.7
Due to a recent update, I have kernel version 3.8-25 installed.  How do I install the older kernel headers so the installation will proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Download the kernel headers from [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/xorg-edgers/quantal/main/base/linux-headers-3.7.0-7-generic) and install that file. You may need to install more dependencies. Just find the files by searching [this website](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org).